# Issue while creating excel workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am trying to create excel using Interop but I am getting below issue when I try to add workbook.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
> HResult=-2147417851   Message=The server threw an exception.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

Basically want I want is to generate excel and save the excel in E drive.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and MSOffice 2016 and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 1.9.0.0.

Struggling to understand whether the problem is with code, dll or server. Please let me know what could be fix or some workaround.

```
public void Excel()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dbConn.GetExcelDataforScheduler();

        // load excel, and create a new workbook
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        // single worksheet
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

        // column headings
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }

        // rows
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // to do: format datetime values before printing
            for (var j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i][j];
            }
        }
        string path = @"E:\";

        workSheet.SaveAs(path);
        excelApp.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: `Visual Studio 2012`？or Visual Studio 2022？ What is `DataTable` `dbConn`?

Comment: Why do you call it with missing value? Just omit the parameter.

Comment: @PalleDue still I am facing same issue.